# Record does not appear in view yet appears in result of query for view

Tags: mysql, view

In MySQL, I have defined a view on two tables as follows:

```
delimiter $$

CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`root`@`localhost`<br/>
SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW `test`.`viewinschrijvingen` AS<br/>
select `i`.`student` AS `student`,<br/>
`i`.`opleidingscode` AS `opleidingscode`,<br/>
`i`.`inschrijvingsvorm` AS `inschrijvingsvorm`,<br/>
`i`.`brin` AS `brin`,<br/>
`i`.`brinvolgnummer` AS `brinvolgnummer`,<br/>
`o`.`onderwijsvorm` AS `onderwijsvorm`,<br/>
`o`.`opleidingniveau` AS `opleidingniveau`,<br/>
`o`.`naamopleidingkort` AS `naamopleidingkort`,<br/>
`o`.`instelling` AS `instelling`,<br/>
`o`.`studielast` AS `studielast`,<br/>
date_format(max(str_to_date(`i`.`datuminschrijving`,'%Y-%m-%d')),'%Y-%m-%d') AS `datuminschrijving`,<br/>
`o`.`gemeentenaam` AS `gemeentenaam` from<br/>
(`test`.`inschrijvingen` `i` left outer join `test`.`opleidingen` `o`<br/>
on((`i`.`opleidingscode` = `o`.`opleidingscode`)))<br/>
group by `i`.`opleidingscode`,`i`.`brin`,`i`.`brinvolgnummer`$$<br/>
```

When I query this view for the information on a specific student:

SELECT * FROM test.viewinschrijvingen WHERE student = '310018717'

the result is empty (no records returned). When I browse through the records in the view, there is no record for student 310018717 (obviously).

However, when I execute the query I used to create the view directly:

```
select `i`.`student` AS `student`,<br/>
`i`.`opleidingscode` AS `opleidingscode`,<br/>
`i`.`inschrijvingsvorm` AS `inschrijvingsvorm`,<br/>
`i`.`brin` AS `brin`,<br/>
`i`.`brinvolgnummer` AS `brinvolgnummer`,<br/>
`o`.`onderwijsvorm` AS `onderwijsvorm`,<br/>
`o`.`opleidingniveau` AS `opleidingniveau`,<br/>
`o`.`naamopleidingkort` AS `naamopleidingkort`,<br/>
`o`.`instelling` AS `instelling`,<br/>
`o`.`studielast` AS `studielast`,<br/>
date_format(max(str_to_date(`i`.`datuminschrijving`,'%Y-%m-%d')),'%Y-%m-%d') AS `datuminschrijving`,<br/>
`o`.`gemeentenaam` AS `gemeentenaam` from<br/>
(`test`.`inschrijvingen` `i` left outer join `test`.`opleidingen` `o`
on((`i`.`opleidingscode` = `o`.`opleidingscode`)))<br/>
WHERE student = '310018717'<br/>
group by `i`.`opleidingscode`,`i`.`brin`,`i`.`brinvolgnummer`<br/>
```

I do get a result (1 record, which is the result I expected). Can anybody help me to find what is causing this behaviour?

Comment: Those queries are not the same. To run the equal query manually do `SELECT * FROM (viewQueryHere) WHERE student=310018717`. It should give same output as the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It probably has to do with your use of MySQL's GROUP BY extension versus the ANSI GROUP BY format. MySQL does not require you to group on every column that is not an aggregate function. For columns that you are not GROUPing on, MySQL can choose whatever value it wants for the column. In your case, you are not using the student field to group and thus it may not be choosing the value you are searching for.

You may want to try this query which uses the ANSI GROUP BY and see if you get the results you want.

```
delimiter $$

CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`root`@`localhost`
SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW `test`.`viewinschrijvingen` AS
select 
  `i`.`student` AS `student`,
  `i`.`opleidingscode` AS `opleidingscode`,
  `i`.`inschrijvingsvorm` AS `inschrijvingsvorm`,
  `i`.`brin` AS `brin`,
  `i`.`brinvolgnummer` AS `brinvolgnummer`,
  `o`.`onderwijsvorm` AS `onderwijsvorm`,
  `o`.`opleidingniveau` AS `opleidingniveau`,
  `o`.`naamopleidingkort` AS `naamopleidingkort`,
  `o`.`instelling` AS `instelling`,
  `o`.`studielast` AS `studielast`,
  date_format(max(str_to_date(`i`.`datuminschrijving`,'%Y-%m-%d')),'%Y-%m-%d') AS `datuminschrijving`,
  `o`.`gemeentenaam` AS `gemeentenaam` 
from `test`.`inschrijvingen` `i` 
left outer join `test`.`opleidingen` `o`
  on `i`.`opleidingscode` = `o`.`opleidingscode`
group by 
  `i`.`student`,
  `i`.`opleidingscode`,
  `i`.`inschrijvingsvorm`,
  `i`.`brin` AS `brin`,
  `i`.`brinvolgnummer`,
  `o`.`onderwijsvorm`,
  `o`.`opleidingniveau`,
  `o`.`naamopleidingkort`,
  `o`.`instelling`,
  `o`.`studielast`,
  `o`.`gemeentenaam`$$
```

Comment: I recreated the view using your suggestion and it seems to work perfectly now. Thank you very much for your quick answer.